# Defining css width/heights in device independent units?

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to occupy the same amount of screen space regardless of device display density.

For example, let's say I have two devices that are each 5 inches wide. The first display has a device-pixel-ratio=1, and the second has a device-pixel-ratio=2.

```
Device 1: 5 inches wide, device-pixel-ratio=1
Device 2: 5 inches wide, device-pixel-ratio=2
```

So the second device has twice as many pixels packed into the same space.

My div style:

```
.myDivStyle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

If I understand correctly, Device 2 would appear to render the div at half the width/height as on Device 1.

If that's the case, is there a way to define our width/height in a device-independent unit? Or do we have to scale all our styles manually on page load etc after we examine the device-pixel-ratio attribute?

Thank you

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question and still wondering: the `div`s should actually occupy the same physical space, despite the difference in hardware pixel density. See [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Redefining your css size by using `em` unit would be good.

Some good links in this reference. Please check these

1. [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)
2. [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C14)
3. [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

All the above links urge that, `em` is best suitable in cases when you want your document to behave well on wide range of devices.

Comment: FYI, From the first link: *"By specifying the padding width in **ems**, the width of the padding is **relative to the font size** of the DIV element."*  For OP's question, he should either stick to `px` (which in CSS is *not* the monitor's actual pixel size), or use `%` which is percentage of the parent container's size.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like you need to work with percentages instead of pixels. So it will use a "percentage" amount of your screen

```
.myDivStyle {
    width:  50%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

It would solve the problem with the ammount of pixels. This would solve the issue if your working with the screen of an Iphone and an Android, since they use two completely different resolutions. For instance, i believe the Iphone uses 320 by .. something, while my own Samsung Galaxy uses i think 480 by something. (dunno the true values)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the devices would come under the following 3 resolutions
1) HVGA-Half of VGA (320 x 240)
2) WVGA- wide VGA(800x 480) - nearly 1.5 times of HVGA
3) HVGA 2x- (640 X 960) - IPHONE 4 uses this resolution

Write seperate css files for the above three resolutions by

```
@Media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
/* css files here*/
}
```

or

```
@Media screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{/* css files here*/

}
```

Do the same with other resolutions. A css class created in 1 resolution should be copy pasted in all three resolutions to get a perfect view. By this way you can showcase a perfect device specific style

Comment: *"A css class created in 1 resolution should be copy pasted in all three resolutions to get a perfect view.".* - if you do this literally, there is no benefit to having the three cases. So, explain what *should* be different between the 3 cases, to adapt to the situation.